# Patch panel with J45 Cat6 female/female connectors very fragile connection

Tags: networking, rack, cat6, rj45

I have a patch panel with the following female/female CAT6 RJ45 snap-in connectors in my cabinet:

[image: rj45 cat6]

It basically serves as a pass-through for the cables at the front to the cables at the back and vice-versa.

The problem is, these connectors are extremely fragile, and if I want to connect two cables at the back via this patch panel (i.e. two of the connectors above is used):

`CableBack1` -> `Con1` -> `CableFront1` -> `Con2` -> `CableBack2`

to connect `CableBack1` to `CableBack2`, the physical connection gets very fragile (I literally need to adjust the positions of the cables to get a connection, and it mostly doesn't work anyways).

So my questions are:

1. Am I having a problem because I might have a different kind of connection (e.g. crossover, etc.)?
2. Is what I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve a clean front/back connection?

Comment: It sounds like poor quality connectors and/or wiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the cabling myself so I was sure of the quality of wiring. **But it was definitely the poor quality keystone jacks (in the picture).** Replaced with these:

[image: digitus keystone]

and the issue is resolved.